# How to use interpolation with solve_ivp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to make some code that calculates the trajectory of a particle, given its initial position and the velocity field. Here is an example of a working bit of code that nearly does what I want:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def velocity(t, coord):
    # velocity gives the velocity of the particle
    # coord gives the coordinate of the particle where
    # coord[0] = x, coord[1] = y and coord[2] = z
    return [coord[0], coord[1], -2 * coord[2]]

n_points = 100
lim = 5

coord0 = [2, 2, 5]
t = np.linspace(0, lim, n_points)
sol = solve_ivp(velocity, [0, lim], t_eval = t, y0 = coord0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ln = ax.plot3D(sol.y[0], sol.y[1], sol.y[2])
ax.set_xlim((0, lim))
ax.set_ylim((0, lim))
ax.set_zlim((0, lim))
plt.savefig('particle_trajectory.png')
```

Here is the outputted figure:

[image]

I want the code to calculate the particle's trajectory if I only have an array describing the velocity field. My plan is to use interpolation so I can calculate the particle's trajectory using a similar method to that shown above. Here is my attempt to do this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def velocity(t, coord):
    # velocity gives the velocity of the particle
    # coord gives the coordinate of the particle where
    # coord[0] = x, coord[1] = y and coord[2] = z
    return [vx_interp([coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]]), \
            vy_interp([coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]]), \
            vz_interp([coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]])]

n_points = 100
lim = 5

# Create an example of a velocity array
x = np.linspace(0, lim, n_points)
y = np.linspace(0, lim, n_points)
z = np.linspace(0, lim, n_points)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
vx = X
vy = Y
vz = -2 * Z

vx_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), vx)
vy_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), vy)
vz_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), vz)

coord0 = [2, 2, 5]
t_range = np.linspace(0, 0.2 * lim, n_points)
sol = solve_ivp(velocity, [0, 2 * lim], t_eval = t_range, y0 = coord0)
```

But this gives the following error:

```
  File "/home/lex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py", line 542, in solve_ivp
    solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
  File "/home/lex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.h_abs = select_initial_step(
  File "/home/lex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/common.py", line 111, in select_initial_step
    f1 = fun(t0 + h0 * direction, y1)
  File "/home/lex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py", line 138, in fun
    return self.fun_single(t, y)
  File "/home/lex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py", line 20, in fun_wrapped
    return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
  File "Python/low_and_lou/stack2.py", line 10, in velocity
    return [vx_interp([coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]]), \
  File "/home/lex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 2509, in __call__
    raise ValueError("One of the requested xi is out of bounds "
ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 2
```

I think the problem is that I am using a 'RegularGridInterpolator' inside of the solve_ivp routine. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you wanting to caculate the particles position given its velocity?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I only know the velocity at a discrete number of points, i.e I only have a velocity array.

Comment: I dont see how that is any different to what you have done in your 1st example? The particle positions are what is stored in `sol['y']`

Comment: In the first example, I have a formula for the velocity field, given by:
vx = x,
vy = y,
vz = -2z.
In the second example, I only provide the velocity at a discrete number of points. To get a formula for the velocity,  I use interpolation. But it seems solve_ivp doesn't like the way the coordinates are called by the interpolated functions (vx_interp, vy_interp, vz_interp).

Comment: Ahh OK I'm with you. First you need to fit a function to your velocity points check out [optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to do this then use that fitted function in `solve_ivp`. These are 2 seperate steps.